# JPA2 criteria query for @OneToMany relation using a hidden column without a field mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa-2.0, hibernate-5.x, jpa-criteria

I have an entity `Instrument` with these fields:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE })
@JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "instrumentId", nullable = false)
public Set<InstrumentSymbol> getSymbols() {
    return this.symbols;
}

@Column
@JsonProperty("statusCode")
public Integer getStatusCode() {
    return statusCode;
}
```

`InstrumentSymbol` has now a column in the database called `symbold_instrumentId` which Hibernate automatically creates but there is no property associated with it. How can I find all `InstrumentSymbol` where `statusCode` is `1`?

I tried

```
    CriteriaBuilder builder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<InstrumentSymbol> query = builder.createQuery(InstrumentSymbol.class);
    Root<InstrumentSymbol> rootSymbol = query.from(InstrumentSymbol.class);

    Subquery<Long> subquery = query.subquery(Long.class);
    Root<Instrument> rootInstrument = subquery.from(Instrument.class);
    subquery.select(rootInstrument.get(Instrument_.instrumentId));
    subquery.where(builder.equal(rootInstrument.get(Instrument_.statusCode), 1));

    query.where(builder.in(rootSymbol.get("symbols_instrumentId")).in(subquery)); // <--- Fails here
```

but that fails with

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [symbols_instrumentId] on this ManagedType [....InstrumentSymbol]
```

Then I tried to add a custom field to my `@StaticMetamodel`:

```
public static volatile SingularAttribute<InstrumentSymbol, Long> symbols_instrumentId; // NOSONAR Hibernate 5 requires this
```

but unfortunately, Hibernate ignores it:

```
    // Hibernate fills these fields for me
    assertEquals("Instrument#instrumentId(BASIC)", Instrument_.instrumentId.toString());
    assertEquals("InstrumentSymbol#instrumentSymbolId(BASIC)", InstrumentSymbol_.instrumentSymbolId.toString());
    // But not this...
    assertEquals(null, InstrumentSymbol_.symbols_instrumentId);
```

How do I create a query which works?

For reference, this is the static meta data for `InstrumentSymbol`:

```
@StaticMetamodel(InstrumentSymbol.class)
public class InstrumentSymbol_ { // NOSONAR Hibernate 5 requires this
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<InstrumentSymbol, String> externalInstrumentSymbolId; // NOSONAR Hibernate 5 requires this
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<InstrumentSymbol, Long> instrumentSymbolId; // NOSONAR Hibernate 5 requires this
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<InstrumentSymbol, String> symbol; // NOSONAR Hibernate 5 requires this
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<InstrumentSymbol, String> symbolType; // NOSONAR Hibernate 5 requires this
}
```

(no column with the FK of `Instrument`). This is the auto generated DDL:

```
create table InstrumentSymbol (
    instrumentSymbolId int8 not null,
    externalInstrumentSymbolId varchar(50) not null,
    symbol varchar(40) not null,
    symbolType varchar(20) not null,
    symbols_instrumentId int8 not null,  /* Additional column, not visible from Java */
    primary key (instrumentSymbolId)
);

alter table InstrumentSymbol 
   add constraint FKcb138lkaiji2wh11275m77byk 
   foreign key (symbols_instrumentId) 
   references Instrument;
```

Comment: What do you mean under "hidden field"?

Comment: Improved the question. `InstrumentSymbol` has a column in the database called `symbold_instrumentId` which Hibernate automatically creates but there is no property associated with it.

Comment: Still can not understand that. Do you use hibernate [schema generation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#schema-generation)? If so, this column should be firstly declared in the `InstrumentSymbol` entity.

Comment: Yes. With both the `@OneToMany` and the `@JoinColumn`, Hibernate will create an additional column in the database with a generated name. There is no need for declare the column in the Java source. This is convenient but causes problems for me when using a JPA Criteria Builder. I can't easily add a field because the same Java type is serialized to JSON.